# How to solve: RPC: Port mapper failure - RPC: Unable to receive errno = Connection refused

Tags: redhat, rpc, mount, nfs

I'm trying to set up a NFS server.

I have two programs server and client, I start the server which starts without errors, then I create a file with the client, the file is created correctly, but when I try to write something in that file I get the error:

```
call failed: RPC: Unable to receive; errno = Connection refused
```

And here is my `rpcinfo -p` output

```
# rpcinfo -p
   program vers proto   port  service
    100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
    100024    1   udp    662  status
    100024    1   tcp    662  status
    100005    1   udp    892  mountd
    100005    1   tcp    892  mountd
    100005    2   udp    892  mountd
    100005    2   tcp    892  mountd
    100005    3   udp    892  mountd
    100005    3   tcp    892  mountd
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
    100227    3   tcp   2049  nfs_acl
    100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
    100227    3   udp   2049  nfs_acl
    100021    1   udp  58383  nlockmgr
    100021    3   udp  58383  nlockmgr
    100021    4   udp  58383  nlockmgr
    100021    1   tcp  39957  nlockmgr
    100021    3   tcp  39957  nlockmgr
    100021    4   tcp  39957  nlockmgr
 536870913    1   udp    997
 536870913    1   tcp    999
```

Please does anyone know how can I solve this problem ?

**NOTE:** I am using my laptop as server and client at the same time.

Comment: You need to provide some additional information; for example what command you're using to mount, content of /etc/exports, etc..  In particular, if you're using NFSv4 you don't need rpcbind (referring to the answer below).

Answer (score 2):

Make sure rpcbind is running. Also, it is a good idea to check if you can see the exports with "showmount -e ".

Comment: Rpcbind is unnecessary if the user is using NFSv4.